# Faster image rotation than scipy.ndimage.rotate

Tags: python, scipy, rotation

Currently, I am rotating images with `scipy.ndimage.rotate`, but the computation time is too slow.
I have shapes of (1, 2001, 2001) and the rotation takes 78% of the computation time.
Is there a way to speed it up, other than:

```py
from scipy.ndimage import rotate

rotate(matrix, angle, reshape=True, cval=nodata, order=0)
```

I thought about multi-core, vector units, GPU. But is this possible with scipy?

Comment: You didn't give us an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In particular you didn't disclose the distribution over typical `angle` values. Is it e.g. often an integer multiple of π/2 radians (90°) ? Or π/4 (45°) ? What loss function do you use to evaluate imperfect [rotation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.rotate.html) transforms, which might be slightly fuzzy or exhibit other artifacts? Clearly [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) would be happy to burn as many cores as you care to give it.

Comment: You mention using a GPU, there is [an equivalent function](https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/reference/generated/cupyx.scipy.ndimage.rotate.html#cupyx-scipy-ndimage-rotate) in cupy for this